# Projects suddenly missing in C# solution

Tags: c#, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2008-sp1

Noticed a strange thing today.

I'm working on a solution that has about 20 projects in it - mostly DLL, three WinFowms applications. It is several years old, was started under .Net Framework 1.1 and then successfully migrated under .Net 2.0 and is now opened in VS2008.

Today I noticed that some of its projects just disappeared from the Solution Tree. I didn't delete them, folders were at place and adding them back even didn't change their source control status. Though I had many unpleasant minutes trying to understand why one of the apps is not working correctly... And it had happened twice today!

All this is very annoying and seems to be a mystery to me. Any suggestions why this could happen and what can be done to prevent such situations?

Comment: Are other developers possibly removing the projects from the solution under source control and checking the solution back in?  Then when you refresh it, the projects are gone?

Comment: Just one? I had several times with visual studio that something went wrong during saving (usually after a hunderd debugging sessions or so). Then it just skips a few of my projects on save. It does not happen a lot though.

Comment: @Steve Danner No, that's not the case. Just for now I am for sure the only one who is working with it.

Comment: @jdv Sounds not very optimistic, but it's a comfort to know I'm not the one who encountered such a problem...